# How to encode image data within an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, image, data-url

I'd like to be able to output an HTML file which includes an image (within the file itself). By Googling, I've come across a couple of ways to do this:

- `javascript:imageData`
- a data URI such as `<IMG SRC="data:image/gif;base64,[...]">`
- `<object ... >` tag (although this uses a data URI, so may inherit the same limitations)

But I don't know which is better supported by browsers, or if there are other alternatives.

Can anyone with some practical experience of this offer me advice? Thanks.

Comment: Another similar-but-not-quite-HTML option would be MHTML. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: MHTML less well-supported by browsers, but readable by Microsoft Word... worth thinking about, maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In regards to browser support, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

> Data URIs are currently supported by
>   the following web browsers:

- Gecko and its derivatives, such as Mozilla Firefox
- Opera
- KDE, through the KIO input/output system. This allows the KDE browser, Konqueror to support data URIs.
- Safari; although Safari's rendering engine, WebKit, is a derivative of Konqueror's KHTML engine, Mac OS X does not share the KIO slaves architecture so the implementations are not shared.
- Safari for the iPhone;
- Google Chrome
- Internet Explorer 8; Microsoft has limited support to certain "non-navigable" content, such as in  tags and CSS rules, for security reasons, including concerns that JavaScript embedded in a data URI may not be interpretable by script filters such as those used by web-based email clients. Data URIs must be smaller than 32k.
- TheWorld Browser; is an IE shell browser which has a built-in support for Data URI scheme

IE does not handle the `<object>` tag correctly, see [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/wrongWithIE/?chapter=Object+Tags) for more details. Briefly, you can't trust IE to display images from it.

The `javascript:imageData` is also not well-supported, since it is used in a lot of cross site scripting attacks.

There are many discussions of [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/emails/BillAitken.html) on the [web](http://www.google.com/search?q=embedded+image), and they all come to the conclusion that there is no good universal way to embed images. If you only need to support a subset of browsers, the data uri may work, or a combination of data uri and javascript.

Comment: Does this mean you favour the javascript:imageData method? or that there's limits to both methods?

Comment: See my above edit - javascript:imageData is probably the least usable method, as many browsers are eliminated vectors for cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: Thanks, jball - the Tarquin link was helpful.

Comment: I tried to pick the most useful one that I've come across. Glad to help!

Comment: +1 data URLs in img are as good as you can get at the moment. Still not *very* good of course.

Answer (score 1):

imageData is more flexible, for instance some ie's restricts data uris to 32k.

Answer (score 1):

The data URI scheme is reasonable well supported except in Internet Explorer before version 8.

JavaScript URIs are, I think, slightly better supported but fail if JS is unavailable.

The best thing you can do is to stick to external image resources.

Comment: Should I supply both options, with a test for JS support?

Comment: You can't. img elements don't have fallback support for the src attribute, and object elements are poorly supported (especially in Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Data URI's won't work in < IE8. IE8 supports them up to 32KB.