# Convert an image into binary data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Get image data in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)
>   [How to encode image data within an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084873/how-to-encode-image-data-within-an-html-file)

Is there any way to convert an image to binary data in javascript and vice versa.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) answers your question:

```
// Code taken from MatthewCrumley (https://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/298479)
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
    // original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Pass the `img` tag to this function. It will return the image in base64 encoding. It will be re-encoded though. So you cannot access the original image data.

Comment: Beat me to it, but this is how I did it as well. +1

Comment: I turned this into a bookmarklet here:  http://jsfiddle.net/bgmort/m26yr/
You open the image you want in its own tab, then run this, and it inserts a textarea on the screen with the data url.

Comment: Instead of the "dataURL.replace" you can do "dataURL.split(',')[1]" which will also work for other formats than "png" or "jpg". :)

Comment: This does a base64 encoding, not straight binary as you would need for a file

Comment: Umm.. how about a way to grab the base64 image-data without the use of canvas? Possible?

Comment: that s base64 not binary.