# Converting remote Image to dataURL, client-side

Tags: javascript, html, data-uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get image data in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)
>   [Convert an image into binary data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript)

**I have:**

A string containing a **link** to an image on a remote server.

**I want:**

To 'get' this image, purely through client-side Javascript, and convert it to a base64 dataURL representation.

**Is this possible?**  **How?**

Comment: This is not the same as the other questions because it is requesting from remote server. The linked question does not have that requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not.

Because the file is on a **remote** server, you can't use the `canvas` element's `getImageData()` method to get the pixel representation of the image.

You'd need to proxy it via a server side script or similar.

Comment: You can set the img element with attribute "crossorigin="anonymous"". This will then allow you to get the image data from the canvas.

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/