# Javascript Get Source Code of an Image

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine opening an image file on your computer with notepad. I am trying to get the same result from an img tag or an Image object with javascript. Is this possible?

Comment: I am morbidly curious as to what you are trying to accomplish! Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370943/retrieving-binary-file-content-using-javascript-base64-encode-it-and-reverse-de

Comment: this might be what you're after, base64 representation of hte image ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript

Comment: @Xander So if the image is really a plain text file, could I recover that text from an img tag or Image object?

Answer (score 0):

You can send an AJAX request to the image URL on the server.

If the server sends good caching headers, that won't even waste bandwidth.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this without ajax, I know how to use xmlhttprequest.