# conversion of file of any type to Binary format in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on attachments in my project.and also we are implementing the browser cache.

when we are online we upload the document and convert that file into binary format and store into Database with the help of Stream class on server side.

the same thing i want to implement in offline mode with indexed db so i want a solution in which i'l be able to convert the file into binary format and store that into Indexed db.

i have gone through the File System API but it supports only Chrome only i want it should support all browsers.

also i have tried Jquery.stream class but i am not able to use that.pls provide any solution for the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To convert text into binary form in JavaScript, you could do it one character at a time:

```
    var text = "TEST";
    var binary = "";
    for (i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        binary +=0+text[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
    } 
   alert(binary); //01010100 01000101 01010011 01010100
```

Comment: I guess you first have to convert it into readable format. Here's more about img converting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript

Comment: my problem is not restricted to Image only,it can upload any type of file.

Comment: You can't convert any format without first being able to identify the format and apply fitting code to convert that specific format.

Comment: you mean to say that for every format i have to write a separate piece of code?

Comment: Of course, you could do everything in one large function but nevertheless you need to identify and handle different formats differently.