# Protractor e2e test case for downloading image file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a web service that generates an dynamic image when /image.gif is called.
How can I get the protractor test to download the file and do an MD5sum on the result?

I had a look at [Protractor e2e test case for downloading pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file/27031924#27031924) but it relies on the browser having a download link to click.

There is no page hosting this image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not get the image to download on my windows setup, using Leo's answer no errors, but I found the following that allowed me to get the base64 data uri which I can "expect" on.

[Convert an image into binary data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript)

```
it('Image is version1)', function() {     
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true                                           
    browser.get(targetUrl);     
    return browser.executeScript(function() {
        var img = document.querySelector('img');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }).then(function (data) {
        expect(data).toEqual(base64VersionOfVersion1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. Note: I haven't tried my solution on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow my [Chrome configuration on that pdf-question link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127745/511069).

Then, instead of clicking something, `browser.get('/image.gif');` should trigger the download.

Wait for the download to complete following [Stephen Baillie solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/511069) or similar.

Finally, NodeJS side of things for the MD5 part, you can use [execSync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec-sync) or something more fancy but execSync will do:

```
var execSync = require('exec-sync');
var md5sum = execSync('md5sum ' + pathToDownloadedFile).split(' ')[0]
// e.g. md5sum //=> "c9b833c49ffc9d48a19d0bd858667188"
```

Comment: I set the conf.js file with the suggested browser capabilities trying both *nix style path for the default_directory and windows style path and although there are no errors no files are created in that folder, even html from other tests.