# "CanvasRenderingContext2D" error at converting jpeg to data-url

Tags: jquery, canvas, jpeg, drawimage, data-url

I worked on my chrome app and the content security policity was nerving. I wanted to get a jpeg image from a json *(string/object/array I don't know)*, but the csp stopped me everytime. Now I know that it's easier with data-links, so [I searched a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript).

```
function getdt(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

//Example
getdt('http://ms01.oe3.fm/oe3metafiles/Pictures/200/929203.22.jpg');
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The Error message is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 
No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

I hope someone can help me :)
*Sorry for my bad english*

Comment: What is  `img`? Provide relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems with your code:

1. As @A.Wolff infers, your img is invalid. Canvas requires a full Image object to draw, not just a URL. So you will have to "new up" an image object `var img=new Image();`
2. The image is loaded asynchronously so you must use put your `drawImage` and `toDataURL` inside the `img.onload` callback. This allows the image to be fully loaded before you try to use it. This also means instead of `return dataURL` you must also put all the code that uses the dataURL inside the onload callback. (Yes, I know, that's messy, but you must do it that way or else the image isn't fully loaded)
3. For good security reasons, to use `toDataURL` your image must be hosted on the same domain as your webpage. If they are different domains, `toDataURL` will fail with a Security Error. This security issue is an involved topic so here is where you can learn what's necessary to avoid the Security Error: http://enable-cors.org/

...And: toDataURL's jpg encoding uses `image/jpeg` so you need to change your regEx.

Here's your code refactored and using an image that is hosted in a way to not create the Security Error:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png";
function start(){

  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL(); // png is the default format

  dataURL=dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");

  // Your dataURL is now available
  // Use it as desired
  alert('The dataURL is '+dataURL.length+' characters long ans starts with: '+dataURL.substring(0,20));

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```