# How to send cropped image with form post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cropper

How can I handle cropped image and send with post? I am using [Cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) library. The HTML codes already in a form element. These codes copied from sample admin template. Cropping works but I cant send files.

[image: HTML Output]

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="image-crop">
        <img src="{{ asset('backend/images/image-upload.png') }}">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>Preview image</h4>
    <div class="img-preview img-preview-sm" style="width: 180px;height:180px;"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-white" id="zoomIn" type="button">Zoom In</button>
        <button class="btn btn-white" id="zoomOut" type="button">Zoom Out</button>
        <button class="btn btn-white" id="rotateLeft" type="button">Rotate Left</button>
        <button class="btn btn-white" id="rotateRight" type="button">Rotate Right</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label title="Upload image file" for="inputImage" class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="inputImage" class="hide">
            Upload new image
        </label>
        <label title="Donload image" id="download" class="btn btn-primary">Download</label>
    </div>


</div>
```

JS:

```
var $image = $(".image-crop > img")
$($image).cropper({
    aspectRatio: 1,
    preview: ".img-preview",
    done: function(data) {
        // Output the result data for cropping image.


    }
});

var $inputImage = $("#inputImage");
if (window.FileReader) {
    $inputImage.change(function() {
        var fileReader = new FileReader(),
                files = this.files,
                file;

        if (!files.length) {
            return;
        }

        file = files[0];

        if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onload = function () {
                $inputImage.val("");
                $image.cropper("reset", true).cropper("replace", this.result);
            };
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a image file");
        }
    });
} else {
    $inputImage.addClass("hide");
}


//Disabled Cropped Image Download
/*
$("#download").click(function() {
    window.open($image.cropper("getDataURL"));
});
*/
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Post Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you do it as a `canvas` first and get the base64 string `toDataURL("image/png")` then catch it in your server side and convert it to image again using the base64 string

kindly take a look at this post.
[Convert an image into binary data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript)

Comment: or just use [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) directly